# How to create a set of ranges from a vector in R?

Tags: r, cumsum

Let's say I have a vector of numbers specifying lengths.

```
x = c(3,5,4,10)
```

Then I run cumsum to get their ranges.

```
cumsum(x)

3  8 12 22
```

How would I pair each up to produce pairs of ranges, starting with 1.

Preferable as a character vector:

```
c("1-3", "3-8", "8-12", "12-22")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `paste` like this:

```
paste(c(1, cumsum(x))[-(length(x)+1)], cumsum(x), sep = "-")
# [1] "1-3"   "3-8"   "8-12"  "12-22"
```

Comment: (+1) `c(1, head(cumsum(x), -1))` seems nicer than `c(1, cumsum(x))[-(length(x)+1)]`

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use `sprintf`

```
 x1 <- c(1, cumsum(x))
 sprintf('%d-%d', x1[-length(x1)], x1[-1])
 #[1] "1-3"   "3-8"   "8-12"  "12-22"
```